# Add node method for a double linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I currently have this but I want to make my list into a double linked list and can't work out how to do.

```
public void addDNode(DNode v)
{
    if(header == tail)
    {

        header = v;
    }
    else
    {
        DNode current = header;
        while (current.nextNode() != null)
        {
            current = current.nextNode();
        }
        current.setNext(v); 
    }
}
```

Comment: java.util.LinkedList is double-linked list. Don't you want ot use it or just look inside add() method?

Comment: The way to solve all linked-list problems is to draw a diagram.  This will help you establish precisely how many pointers/references need to be updated.

Comment: @user979236: Then how did you write this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void addDNode(DNode v) {
    if (header == null) {  // means list is empty, so add first element
        if (tail != null)  
            throw new AssertionError(); // if head points to null then tail should too

        header = v;
        tail = header;  // first element so (head == tail)
    } else {
        tail.setNext(v);
        v.setPrev(tail);
        v.setNext(null);
        tail = v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou but what is the variable last?

Comment: It's generally frowned-upon to just give people complete code snippets for their homework problems...

Comment: Only thing that's missing is an overloaded `addDNode()` method that does the same thing.

Comment: @Oli Sharp of you to notice; I only figured it out by going through his question history.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what a doubly linked list is: [doubly linked list article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list)
This is a one way to implement it in Java: [doubly linked list example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Doublylinkedlistwithdatastructure.htm)

Search on the internet, try implementing it and then if you have some issues ask here ;)